# RosoutPanel not included in Fuerte?

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, rxtools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rxtools libraries do not seem to be included in Fuerte. Is there any way to install them (or have they been moved to a new place maybe)? I have connected a RosoutPanel to my GUI, so it would be nice to be able to use it in the new relase too.
To clarify, i'm looking for the C++ source code, not rxconsole. I'm including rxtools/rosout_panel.h in my code, but can not find it in Fuerte.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32738/rosoutpanel-not-included-in-fuerte?/) by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-26**:
The rxconsole command works for me. What OS are you using? Did you install from source or binaries?

**Comment by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on 2012-04-26**:
The rxconsole command works, but i'm using the C++ library functions for rxtools::RosoutPanel. In Electric the code is located in stacks/rx/rxtools/src/ but in Fuerte the stack/rx is empty and the rxtools package has moved to share/ but there is no src directory, only bin/. I installed from binaries

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-04-27**:
I was under the impression that rxtools was getting deprecated in favor of the new ros_gui package that should be coming along shortly.  You may want to investigate that alternative.

**Comment by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on 2012-04-27**:
Seems a bit odd to remove the old before having an alternative ready...

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-27**:
Yes, wx is deprecated in favor of Qt as a long-term goal due to cross-platform portability issues. But, http://ros.org/wiki/rxtools says its interfaces are "stable", with no deprecation indication. So, there is a defect somewhere: either in code or documentation.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-04-28**:
Sorry, I was mistaken, the correct phrasing is that it is "End of Life" http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte#Migrating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like those C++ interfaces were left out when `rxtools` was converted to the new catkin build system. The `rxtools::RosoutPanel` is a documented interface, and its omission was probably unintentional.

Please open a defect ticket for the `rx` component on the [ROS Trac system](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2